# Wordpress Customizer HTML manipulation and dropdown menu

Tags: php, wordpress, customizer, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a section in the wordpress customizer with a few different "subsections" in a dropdown menu. Like in the following image:

[image]

I would like to open a subsection when you make click on "H1", for example, with some new controls. I know how to use `add_panel`, `add_section`, `add_control` but not how to manipulate the `html` code of each section. It's possible because i saw it in several themes and plugins but i can't find any way to do it. I was thinkig to add some `html` blocks and hide/show by `jquery` with the `customize_controls_print_footer_scripts` but `javascript` functions doesn't seems to work properly. It's frustrating because i cant find any information about that on internet